# Centering checkbox in table column

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to center checkboxes in a table column without success. The checkboxes always appear left aligned whatever alignment I use. The weird things is that same code works if I change v-checkbox for v-btn. Is there any solution to this problem?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QVqqVP

Here the simple view code:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-data-table :items="apps" :headers="headers" hide-actions class="elevation-1">
            <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
                <td class="text-xs-left">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">{{props.item.app_name}}</h6>
                </td>
                <td class="text-xs-center">
                    <v-checkbox color="primary"/> 
                </td>
            </template>
            </v-data-table>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Here the Vue app:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    apps: [{'app_name':"row1"}, {'app_name':"row2"}]
  })
})
```

Comment: Share the code snippet please. Is this nothing related to CSS ?

Comment: `text-align: center` on the `<td>`

Comment: @connexo sorry, but these does not work. Same result. You can check it in the pep I attached.

Comment: another approach, check [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YOrERg), wrap your checkbox inside on your own div then custom this div.

Comment: Hi, it would be helpful to mention which version of Vuetify you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it cannot be centered on the `td` given the HTML structure you have:

[image]

The actual checkbox is hidden deep inside many nested `div` elements. Each of these has `display: block;` by default which means it grabs all horizontals space its parent element allows it to get.

On top of that, the element you're using is display using flexbox.

You can center your checkboxes adding the following CSS code:

```
.v-input__slot {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: So, is there any solution to this problem? You stated the cause of the problem and I appreciate it, but can't find a solution to it.

Comment: Added the solution.

Comment: If you use the CSS override trick, make sure you are not doing so in a scoped style tag. Otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution for Vuetify 2.4.0

```
<td class="text-center">
  <v-checkbox class="d-inline-flex"></v-checkbox>
</td>
```

Adding

> class="d-inline-flex"

on `v-checkbox` component

Comment: Also works with Vuetify 3

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution for Vue 2.6.10

```
<td class="text-xs-center">
    <v-checkbox :input-value="props.item.closed" readonly hide-details class="align-center justify-center"></v-checkbox>
</td>
```

Adding

> class="align-center justify-center"

On checkbox do the trick

Comment: I would say it's a combo of adding the `align-center justify-center` along with adding the `hide-details` on the `<v-checkbox` the details on the checkbox are what was causing problems for me by pushing my whole checkbox parent div to be taller

Comment: Thanks @Zombiesplat for mentioning `hide-details` — I was a bit confused about why vertical padding was being added

Comment: `readonly` probably isn't part of the solution.....